# Modifying fontSize throws an error - TypeError: "fontSize" is read-only

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a Vue.js application. In my component, I want to make sure that the text inside of a div fits its content. Here's the logic that I have in my `mounted` hook:

```js
  mounted() {
    const front = this.$refs.frontContainer;
    const subject = this.$refs.subjectContainer;
    const fontSize = 1.1;
    while (front.offsetHeight < front.scrollHeight) {
      fontSize -= 0.05;
      subject.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'em';
    }
  }
```

The template (simplified) is as follows:

```html
<template>
<div class="front-data" ref="frontContainer">
  <span ref="subjectContainer" class="subject">{{ event.subject }}</span>
</div>
</template>
```

Whenever I load my page I see the errors:

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: "fontSize" is read-only"

> TypeError: "fontSize" is read-only

Why doesn't it work? I found on [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_fontsize.asp) that I should be able to set the fontSize.

Comment: You declared it as `const`... constants are, like their name suggests,, cannot be changed. Use `let`

Comment: I was sure the error was at the `subject.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'em';` line. Of course, you are right, I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use let instead of const if you are modifying values

```
let fontSize = 1.1;
```